# How to find out the simulator orientations?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

iam developing one app .In that i want to find out the iphone orientations.I written the code for that one.Is there any way to find out the simulator orientations.

Comment: same thing works for simulator

Comment: I found the orientations based on x,y axis values.Below is the my code.float angle = atan2(yy, xx); base don this angle i mention the orintation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremy's answer is missing an exceedingly important piece of information about `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` - as per the Apple documents:

> The value of this property always returns 0 unless orientation notifications have been enabled by calling beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications.

Before you call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` you must first call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]`.

When you're done, you should also call `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` at some point.

However, it is worth noting that the simulator can at times fail to pass orientation changes through: I would strongly recommend testing your orientation changes on a device. There are edge cases you won't see on the simulator that will definitely occur on actual hardware.

Answer (score 2):

This little snippet should work both in the simulator and on a physical device.  You also need a few other bits of code for it it work as lxt pointed out.

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

Example:

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    NSLog("The device orientation is portrait!");
else
    NSLog("The device orientation is NOT portrait!");
```

Comment: See my answer below. You need to match this with a notification call.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I didn't know about the extra snippets needed to get it to work.